# Como puedo hacer un enlace desde un $row?

Tags: php, url

Hola queridos amigos tengo un problema que me gustaria poder resolver y es que tengo un codigo php que necesito colocar una url,para ir a la pagina de activacion de la cuenta, ya he intentado colocar el url pero me da error de pagina en blanco, el codigo es este:

```
 <td><a href=\"http://travianforce.com.es/activate.php?id=&q="</a></td>
```

lo que necesito colocar es este url:

```
http://travianforce.com.es/activate.php?id=&q=
```

El codigo php en donde quiero colocarlo es este:

```
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" id="member">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="10">Players Not 

Activated</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="on">#</td>
            <td class="on">ID</td>
            <td class="on">Username</td>
            <td class="on">Email</td>
            <td class="on">Tribe</td>
            <td class="on">Activation Code</td>
            <td class="on">Act 2??</td>
            <td class="on">Time</td>
            <td class="on">PLAY!</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM 

".TB_PREFIX."activate";
            $result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], 

$sql);
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
                $i++;
                if($row['tribe'] == 1) {$tribe = 

"Roman"; }
                elseif($row['tribe'] == 2) {$tribe 

= "Teuton"; }
                elseif($row['tribe'] == 3) {$tribe 

= "Gaul"; }

                echo "
                <tr>
                    <td>".$i."</td>
                    <td>".$row['id']."</td>
                    <td>".$row['username']."</td>
                    <td><a href=\"mailto:".
                    $row['email']."\">".$row['email']."</a></td>
                    <td>".$tribe."</td>
                    <td>".$row['act']."</td>
                    <td>".$row['act2']."</td>
                    <td class=\"hab\">".date
                    ('d:m:Y H:i', $row['timestamp'])."</td>                   
                    <td><a href=\"http://travianforce.com.es/activate.php?id=&q=">Yes</a></td>
                </tr>";
            }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

no se que estoy haciendo mal porque me da error de pagina en blanco, creo que el problema esta en la parte de $row, no soy un experto en programacion pero se lo basico jeje.

les estaria muy agradecido si me pueden ayudar, muchas gracias y feliz noche! =)

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta, ¿podrías detallarla un poco más?

Comment: Hola jeje lo que necesito es reemplazar la url "mailto:".$row['email']."\">".$row['email']." por esta otra http://travianforce.com.es/activate.php?id=&q= , pero cuando la coloco me da error de pagina en blanco y no se porque, el codigo php es este:

Comment: ¿Y qué has probado? ¿Qué es lo que no te funciona?

Comment: lo que he probado es hacer esta url:<td><a href=\"http://travianforce.com.es/activate.php?id=&q=">Yes</a></td>, pero no me funciona

Comment: Te falta poner el `http://`

Comment: Hola ya he añadido el http:// pero me sigue dando el mismo error, no sera que tengo que declarar algo?